# Use of noop format in Pyspark dataframe write

Tags: pyspark

Can someone please let me know the use/How it works the command
`data.write.format("noop").mode("overwrite").save()` in
Pyspark 3.0?

Comment: noop = no operation. The statement will execute but it won't write anything. useful for testing/benchmarking things without writing the data. here is some reference https://towardsdatascience.com/performance-in-apache-spark-benchmark-9-different-techniques-955d3cc93266

Comment: .write.format("noop").mode("overwrite").save()

Answer (score 2):

The "noop" command is useful when you need to simulate a write without any data, for example, imagine that you want to check the performance of your job, however you just want to check the effects of saving to your storage without doing it properly.